# Styling javascript function *show/hide* CSS/HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, show-hide, styling

How would i style the read more and show less? ive tried styling #tag1 but this just alters the 'read more' text that first appears

Heres the JS

```
<script>
function toggleAndChangeText(divId, tagId) {
     $("#"+divId).toggle();
     if ($("#"+divId).css('display') == 'none') {
          $('#'+tagId).html('Read More <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i>');
     }
     else {
          $('#'+tagId).html('Show Less <i class="icon-circle-arrow-up"></i>');
     }
}
```

and the html

```
        <a id="tag1" href="javascript:toggleAndChangeText('a1', 'tag1');">
        <p>Read More <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i></p> </a>
```

Here is what the text looks like during every section...

[image]

The first one is when you first see the button.
Then the user clicks on it and the 'Show Less' appears as you can see the button is further to the left and less padding on the bottom. when the user then goes to close the show less button, read more appears but stays in the same position as the show less.

My question is how would i go about styling the interactive read more/show less ones so they are in the position the first read more is? sorry if this is confusing!

Comment: Please provide us a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
$('#'+tagId).html('<p>Read More <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i></p>');
```

I guess you have a padding or margin on your paragraphs

Actually, you're replacing

```
<a id="tag1" href="javascript:toggleAndChangeText('a1', 'tag1');">
    <p>Read More <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i></p> </a>
```

By

```
<a id="tag1" href="javascript:toggleAndChangeText('a1', 'tag1');">
    Read More <i class="icon-circle-arrow-down"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:
Style:

```
<style>
    #open{
    display: none;}
    </style>
```

HTML:

```
<p id="open">Content goes here</p>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="click1"><span class="text"><strong>Read More</strong><img src="icon-show.png" /></span><span class="text" style="display:none;"><strong>Show less</strong><img src="icon-hide.png" /></span></a>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#click1').click(function() {
      $('p#open').slideToggle();

    $('span.text').toggle();
       return false;
        });
         });
        </script>
```